# How to put greater words at the end when using insertion sort?

Tags: java, arrays, insertion-sort, compareto

Im working on some code that will organize my string into alphabetical order but I realized when a word is greater than all of the others, it puts it at the front. How do I make it so it gets put into the back of the list of words?

```
public class SortingText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          int i,j;
          String key;
          String[] inputArray = {"Fourscore","and","seven","years","ago","our"};
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
          for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length; j++) { //the condition has changed
            key = inputArray[j];
            i = j - 1;
            while (i >= 0) {
              if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) > 0) {//here too
                break;
              }
              inputArray[i + 1] = inputArray[i];
              i--;
            }
            inputArray[i + 1] = key;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
          }
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
        }
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't the word length, but that you don't sort case insensitive and treat capital and non-capital letters different. Capital letters are sorted first in your logic. Try change the first word to "fourscore" and you'll see that it won't get sorted at the beginning despite its length

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you use compareTo to compare the 2 items. Lets update this this to use a Comparator:

```
// Sort by the natural order
Comparator<string> cmp = Comparator.naturalOrder();
...
if (cmp.compare(key, inputArray[i]) > 0) {//here too
```

Since you want ito ignore the case during sorting, you need to use a case insensitive comparator:

```
Comparator cmp =  String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER;
// Result = [ago, and, Fourscore, our, seven, years]
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.compareTo()` is *case-sensitive*, meaning `A` is "smaller" than `a`. That's why that `"Fourscore"` is at the beginning of the sorted array.

You can use `compareToIgnoreCase()` instead of `compareTo()` to ignore the case when comparing elements:

```java
if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(inputArray[i]) > 0) {
```

#### [Demo](https://ideone.com/MTkBMn)